# Django annotation per day time range

Tags: python, django, django-annotate

I am using the following query to get a sum per day:

```
orders = OrderM.objects.filter(user=request.user) \
         .annotate(day=TruncDay('datetime_added')) \
         .values('day') \                                   
         .annotate(sum=Sum(F('orderd__good_count'))) \
         .order_by('-day')
```

as expected each day changes at 00:00 midnight! I want to change this behaviour so that the **sum** to be generated on periods from 06:00 to 06:00 of each *day*. I think that the use of `datetime__range = ..` will do, but I'm not experienced in django queries.

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the work:

```
from django.db.models import DateTimeField, ExpressionWrapper, F
from django.utils.timezone import timedelta

expression = F('datetime_added') - timedelta(hours=6)
wrapped_expression = ExpressionWrapper(expression, output_field=DateTimeField())

orders = OrderM.objects.filter(user=request.user) \
               .annotate(day=TruncDay(wrapped_expression)) \
               .values('day') \
               .annotate(sum=Sum(F('orderd__good_count'))) \
               .order_by('-day')
```

Time portion of `TruncDay('datetime_added')` is 00:00 midnight by definition.
So we have to subtract 6 hours from each `datetime` field before we truncate. The following will actually change the day portion, after 6 in the morning!

```
`TruncDay( F('datetime_added') - timedelta(hours=6) )`
```

The use of `ExpressionWrapper` is essential, since I get

> Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field

, otherwise (and I don't know why!).